# Не могу исправить ошибку: ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

много раз переделывал код, всё равно выдает ошибку "ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль." Напишите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку?

```
import sys
from check import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Вешаем на кнопку функцию PoemCheck
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.PoemCheck)

    # Описываем функцию 
    def PoemCheck(self):
        # Очищаем второе текстовое поле
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText("")
        # В переменную stroki получаем текст из левого поля ввода
        stroki=self.ui.textEdit.toPlainText()
        # Получаем массив строк разделив текст по знаку переноса строки
        mas=stroki.split('\n')
        # Обнуляем переменную где будут копиться проверенные строки
        rezultat=''
        # Массив гласных букв для подсчёта колиества слогов
        glasnye=['а','е','ё','и','о','у','э','ю','я','ы']
        # Перебираем каждую строку стиха
        for stroka in mas:
            kol=0 # Переменная с количеством гласных в строке
            # Перебираем все буквы в строке
            for w in stroka.lower():
                # По очереди сравниваем буквы с гласными
                for bukva in glasnye:
                    # Если буква гласная увеличиваем счетчик
                    if(w==bukva): kol=kol+1
            if(kol>0):
                # Добавляем в конце строки количество слогов
                rezultat=rezultat+stroka+' - '+str(kol)+' слогов'+'\n'
            else:
                rezultat=rezultat+'\n'
        # Выводим в правое поле переменную результат с количеством слогов в         строке
        self.ui.textEdit_2.setText(rezultat)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

chek.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'check.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.8.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 444)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 40, 381, 301))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 40, 371, 301))
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 350, 761, 41))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 371, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 10, 371, 16))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Подсчёт количества    слогов в стихах"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Посчитать количество слогов в строках стиха"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Скопируйте проверяемый стих в поле ниже:"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Здесь вы увидите количество слогов в строках:"))
```

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `check.py`

Comment: опубликуйте полное сообщение ошибки, которую вы получаете.

Comment: Приме, который вы опубликовали, работает правильно. Напишите какую операционную систему вы используете? Какая версия `python` у вас установлена?. Как вы устанавливали `PyQt5` и какую версию?

Comment: Используете виртуальное окружение? Пробовали без него/с ним? Лично у меня такая ошибка была именно с окружением, во внешней среде работало.

Comment: S. Nick, ОС Windows 10, python 3.7.4, устанавливал через командную строку Windows, PyQt5 v. 12.7.0. Полное сообщение ошибки "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\M14\Prog\Python\PyQt\slog\main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from check import *
  File "D:\M14\Prog\Python\PyQt\slog\check.py", line 9, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найден указанный модуль."

Comment: Используете виртуальное окружение? Пробовали без него/с ним?