# Не импортируется библиотека PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

Импортирую PyQt5 ошибок нет, импортирую любой модуль, например, PyQt5.QtCore, сразу   появляется ошибка : `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Не найден указанный модуль.`. 
Я уже и переустанавливал, и откатывал до старой версии, и вручную ставил библиотеку все безрезультатно. Устанавливал через pip последнюю версию, так там вообще другая ошибка: `ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtGui: %1 не является приложением Win32.`. 
В общем не знаю что делать. Вот пути, если интересно:

```py
import sys
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Python\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Python\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python\\lib', 'C:\\Python', 'C:\\Users\\winda\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Python\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058503/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-importerror-dll-load-failed-%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica проблема не решена.